# Single Mail For Multiple Events

Tags: apex

I had created event for 3 days, (I had used Einstein standard functionality for this), but the user is getting 3 mails for 3 days. I want to send only one mail
here is my code:

```
if (RecurringType == 'daily') {
    //while (startDate <= endDate) {
    // DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(startDate, actualTime);
    Event newEvent = new Event();
    newEvent.Subject = subjectOfMeeting;
    newEvent.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    newEvent.WhatId = recordId;
    newEvent.IsRecurrence = true;
    newEvent.RecurrenceStartDateTime = dt;
    newEvent.RecurrenceEndDateOnly = endDate; // Recurring for 30 days
    newEvent.RecurrenceType = 'RecursDaily'; // Recurs daily
    // newEvent.IsAllDayEvent = true; // All-day event
    //newEvent.ActivityDate = startDate;
    newEvent.RecurrenceInterval = 1;
    newEvent.DurationInMinutes = durationOfMeeting; // 24 hours in minutes
    eventList.add(newEvent);
}

insert eventList;

list<EventRelation> eventRelationListToInsert = new list<EventRelation>();
list<Id> eventId = new list<Id>();   // adding event ids ;
system.debug('List ofEvent are::-->>'+eventList);
// for(Event myEventID : eventList){
system.debug('inside event loop');
for(Id conId:participantIDs){
    system.debug('inside ID loop');
    EventRelation eventReln = new EventRelation();
    eventReln.EventId = eventList[0].Id;
    eventReln.RelationId = conId;
    // eventReln.IsParent = eventList[0].RecurrenceDayOfMonth == 1;
    eventReln.IsParent = false;
    eventReln.IsInvitee = true;
    eventReln.Status = 'New';
    eventRelationListToInsert.add(eventReln);
}
    
insert eventRelationListToInsert;
```